# How can I compile an XSLT file to bytecode and run it in a browser?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file and a corresponding XSL stylesheet which I am using to transform to XML to an XHTML document. This may be a stupid question, but how do I execute the XSL file? Right now  when I'm opening my XSL file into the browser, a copy of my code with color codes and appropriate formatting is displayed. However, obviously I wish to see the output of the program. I researched a bit and figured out that the XSLT file isn't being compiled into byte code and therefore can't run. Is there some type of processing application which does this job to compile an XSLT file?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: You can have a look at [xslfiddle](http://xslfiddle.net/)

Comment: Could you refer to your research that talked about compiling an XSLT into bytecode? That's the first I've heard of something like tha.

Comment: I might have understood it wrong then :/ This is my first day of XML, XSL, XSLT and other scripting languages so cope with me haha! 

Quote: "The water is muddied by XSL (both XSLT and XSL:FO) which use XML syntax to implement a declarative programming language. In these special cases you can ‘execute’ an XML file, by running a processing application like Saxon, which compiles the directives specified in XSLT files into Java bytecode to process XML." -

http://xml.silmaril.ie/execute.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Bytecode" is a red herring. The issue is how to supply XML to an XSLT program and have that program be executed. There is no one way to do this because it depends on the environment you're working in.

To get you started, here's one way. Most browsers understand the `xsl-stylesheet` processing-instruction. So you can serve up an XML file like this to a browser:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="my-xsl-stylesheet.xsl"?>
<myxmlfile>...</myxmlfile>
```

When you load your xml file in the browser it will retrieve `my-xsl-stylesheet.xsl` from the server, apply it to the current xml, and display the result. (Make sure your files are being served with the correct MIME type, e.g. `application/xml`.)

But there are many more options. You can transform the XML on the server as the documents are retrieved. You can precompile all your XML to html and serve the html to the browsers directly. If you have a browser that supports programmatic transformation of XML, you can use an HTML file with some javascript to load the XML and XSLT using XMLHttpRequest and run the transformation on the browser.

Comment: I did reference the xml stylesheet as quoted by you and other answerers. And I understood that I can handle the transformation of an xml document on the client-side by using java script or on the server side by using asp. However I can't understand why the XSL file code is being displayed in the browsers instead of the desired output. The XSL and XML file are in the same directory too.. So By using the stylesheet tag it's supposed to be enough for it to run? :/

Comment: You add the stylesheet to the *xml*, and you load the *xml* url in the browser. It sounds like you are loading the *xslt* url, which isn't correct. If this is not what is happening, you need to show us some code we can run that reproduces your problem.

Comment: how can I load the xml url in the browser though?

Comment: The same way you do anything else: enter the url in the address bar: `http://example.org/path/to/my/xmlfile.xml`

Comment: Ok I managed thx :) .. sorry for the noobish questions.. I had to learn XML, XSLT, javascript and ASP all in one day to be able to produce a transformation in this way, transforming on the client-side and on the server-side... so my mind is a little confused haha!

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing the XSL file in the XML file ?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="class.xsl"?>
```

When you load the XML file in the browser, it the browser will load the XSL file and apply the rules to the XML data.

Answer (score 0):

The [`xml-stylesheet` processing instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038304/xslt-pi-and-stylesheet-parameters) is used to specify a XSLT stylesheet to be used to transform the XML document.

Comment: I used an xml stylesheet into my xml file and referenced the xsl file which is in the same directory.. What can be wrong then? :/

Comment: You stated, "Right now when I'm opening my XSL file into the browser."  Don't you mean, your XML file is loaded in the browser?

Comment: Oh! This may be the thing!.. no I was opening it.. Do I have to use a java script function to load the file into the browser?

Comment: No. You navigate to the XML document as you would any other file.

Comment: If you open the XML file directly from the filesystem Chrome will not perform the transformation. If possible get it through a web server or the Firefox web browser.